# What is the maximum number of rows in column set with varchar

Tags: mysql, varchar

What is the maximum number of rows allowed in a column set with a variable length (varchar) data type?

Answer (score 1):

There is not any limitation on the number of rows, it's about the size. So, becuase the `varchar` has variable size, depend on `string lenght`, the maximum number of row is variable too.
But if we consider maximum `varchar` size (max lenght of string) for each rows i.e., 65535 Bytes, and max size for database i.e., 64T, So, with a simple divison (64T/64KB) you can find your answer, its about `10^9` rows.

Answer (score 0):

A varchar column doesn't make it any special. Storage capacity depends on the engine you're using, but your main concern is the space you can offer, not how much mysql can handle. Read more about it [here for MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) or [here for InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html).